# What's the difference between CRS-1 and CRS-3

Tags: cisco

What are the differences between the CRS-1 and CRS-3 platforms? I know the CRS-3 is the upgrade to CRS-1.

Do I need a new chassis to upgrade to CRS-3? Or is a CRS-1 chassis upgradable to a CRS-3 just upgrading the RP, MSC and Fabric cards?

What is upgraded to get from CRS-1 to CRS-3? All of the below or just a few pieces?

- Chassis
- RP
- Fabric Card
- MSC

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

In March 2010, Cisco announced the introduction of the CRS-3 family. The switching capacity of this new product-line is increased more than three times as each switch-fabric line card can process 140 Gbit/s instead of 40 Gbit/s as in the old system. According to Cisco, the current users can upgrade to the CRS-3 system step by step and without serious outage as the chassis, interface-cards, management-systems etc. are the same. The main changes are in the switching-fabric and the option to use new interface modules supporting these higher speeds (14 or 20 × 10 Gb interfaces and 1 × 100 Gb ethernet interface).

For information about migrating from a Cisco CRS-1 to a Cisco CRS-3 chassis, refer to the Cisco CRS-1 Carrier Routing System to Cisco CRS-3 Carrier Routing System Migration Guide at the URL http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps5763/prod_installation_guides_list.html